# typo3: How to get tstamp and crdate of new persisted extbase entry

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

When persisting a new object I want to get the `tstamp` and `crdate` of that item. After persisting I can access its uid by `object->getUid()` but `object->getCrdate()` leads to a null result.

I tried to read the object with `findByUid(object->getUid())` but I only get the cached result which is null.

How can I get `tstamp` and `crdate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [only UID and PID are added to objects](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/8e6177874b1e3735e0dba56d0d32424f4a34b833/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Backend.php#L703-L704) right after they where persisted, any other autogenerated value is not accessible right away.

The only option you have is get yourself an instance of the Extbase persistence `Session`, e.g. by dependency injection, unregister your object (otherwise you'll only be able to retrieve this very instance) and use your repository to retrieve your object once more through the persistence:

```
$this->persistenceSession->unregisterObject($yourObject);
$yourObject = $this->yourObjectRepository->findByIdentifier($yourObject->getUid());
```

Comment: I thought so. Thank you for the methods names !

Answer (score 1):

I remember that I once added crdate and tstamp to the model of the object. (Maybe they have to be added to the TCA as well.)

Comment: I did so. But those are only retrieved from database when you load an already persisted object. If you create an object and persist it those are not directly updated as Mathias Brodala has pointed out.